# Is it possible to include text within empheq

Tags: empheq

Right now, I have

```
\begin{gather}
Eq1
\\ Eq2
\\ Eq3
\end{gather}

where variables ... are defined as

\begin{gather}
Eq4
\\ Eq5
\end{gather}
```

I would like to put a box around all of this including the text "where variables ... are defined as".  Is it possible to do this using the `empheq` environment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, and you have several options depending on the desired result. Below I show six different possibilities.

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[vmargin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{empheq}

\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}[box=\fbox]{gather}
Eq1
\\ Eq2
\\ Eq3
\\ \notag\text{where variables ... are defined as}
\\ Eq4
\\ Eq5
\end{empheq}

\begin{empheq}[box=\fbox]{gather}
Eq1
\\ Eq2
\\ Eq3
\\ \notag\text{\parbox{.7\linewidth}{where variables ... are defined as}}
\\ Eq4
\\ Eq5
\end{empheq}

\begin{empheq}[box=\tcbhighmath]{gather}
Eq1
\\ Eq2
\\ Eq3
\\ \notag\text{where variables ... are defined as}
\\ Eq4
\\ Eq5
\end{empheq}

\begin{empheq}[box=\tcbhighmath]{gather}
Eq1
\\ Eq2
\\ Eq3
\\ \notag\text{\parbox{.7\linewidth}{where variables ... are defined as}}
\\ Eq4
\\ Eq5
\end{empheq}

\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,oversize,breakable,colframe=cyan,colback=cyan!20,top=-\abovedisplayskip,bottom=0pt]
\begin{gather}
Eq1
\\ Eq2
\\ Eq3
\end{gather}
where variables ... are defined as
\begin{gather}
Eq4
\\ Eq5
\end{gather}
\end{tcolorbox}

\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\fcolorbox{orange}{orange!10}{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
\vskip-\abovedisplayskip
\begin{gather}
Eq1
\\ Eq2
\\ Eq3
\end{gather}
where variables ... are defined as
\begin{gather}
Eq4
\\ Eq5
\end{gather}
\end{minipage}}}

\end{document}
```

### Explanation

- In options one through four, instead of two `gather` environments I used just one. The text was written using `\text`.
- In options two and four, the text was additionally placed inside a `\parbox`, so you can control its width and have possible line breaks.
- Options one and two use a standard `empheq` environment with `\fbox` as the framing method.
- Options three and four use the interaction between `tcolorbox` and `empheq`; the framing method is `\tcbhighmath`.
- In option five, a `tcolorbox` was used to surround both `gather` environments and the text; page breaks are allowed.
- In option six, a `\fcolorbox` was used to surround both `gather` environments and the text; page breaks are *not* allowed since a `minipage` was used.

Comment: Thanks for your quick and helpful response.  With tcolorbox, is there a way to change the width of the frame?

Comment: @KevinB You're welcome. I edited my answer (in case you didn't noticed it). Regarding your question, you can use `boxrule` as in `\begin{tcolorbox}[oversize,breakable,colframe=cyan,colback=cyan!20,boxrule=0.4pt]
...\end{tcolorbox}` (change `0.4pt` to the desired value.)

Comment: I did see your edit.  Thanks for such a thorough answer with the different options.  I like the tcolorbox option the best.  However when I use boxrule:

    \begin{tcolorbox}[oversize,breakable,colframe=black,colback=white!20,boxrule=0.4 p‌​t]


 I'm getting an error

" Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again>
p
l.351 ...ck,colback=white!20,boxrule=0.4 p‌​t]
Dimensions can be in units of em, ex, in, pt, pc,
cm, mm, dd, cc, nd, nc, bp, or sp; but yours is a new one!"

Comment: @KevinB for some reason there's a strange character in your code in the `pt` part (probably a result of copy-paste). Delete `0.4 pt` and write it again directly from your keyboard.

Comment: Thanks, that works.  Unfortunately with tcolorbox, the equations I want to box are getting split into two boxes because they extend beyond the bottom of the page.  Therefore, I think I will use fcolorbox because as you mentioned, that doesn't allow page breaks.  With fcolorbox, how should I specify the frame width?  Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @KevinB delete `breakable` from the `tcolorbox` options and no page breaks will occur.

Comment: it would be nice to get rid of the extra blank line at the top of examples 5 and 6.

Comment: @barbarabeeton You're right. I tried to better balnce the spaces above and below for cases five and six. I think it looke better now. Thanks.

Comment: @Gonzalo  In the case where the "breakable" argument is used, is there any way to have it look like one box (and not be two separate boxes) if it extends beyond one page?  In other words, I mean I would like to have the bottom line of the box not be drawn on page 1 and the top line of the box not be drawn on page 2, so that it looks like one continuous box encompassing two pages rather than two separate boxes.

Comment: @KevinB Sure. Add `enhanced` to the options: `\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,oversize,breakable...]`. I've added this as an edit.

Comment: @Gonzalo:  After adding "enhanced" to the options, there is a very thin bottom line on page 1 and a very thin top line on page 2. This is better than the normal thick line before, but I would prefer not to have any line on the bottom of page 1 and top of page 2. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: @KevinB To get rid of the very thin line: replace `enhanced` by `enhanced jigsaw`.